# Lambda truncating first few characters

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

```py
import zipfile
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
source_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('4flow-dev-ingest-alpegatm')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('HELLO zi')
    lst_of_mars_keys = []
    for item in source_bucket.objects.all():
        if 'Data' in str(item):
            if 'archive' not in str(item):
                lst_of_mars_keys.append(item.key)
                print('key', item.key)
```

I have a simple lambda func that reads keys from a bucket. However, when I print it, in the execution results output, I see this:

```
0-ffk-mars/1635156990/DataPump_491414026_1635156990.zip
key 20-ffk-mars/1635158784/DataPump_491433569_1635158784.zip
key 20-ffk-mars/1635160599/DataPump_491448916_1635160599.zip
```

Why is it not printing "Hello" or "key" for the first line?

Comment: Which Python version are you using? Do you have the same problem when you run the code locally? If not, how do the complete log records in CloudWatch look?

Comment: Could just be an issue with the Lambda console. Check the logs in CloudWatch to be sure.

Comment: The fact that it is not printing `HELLO zi` suggests that the function was not Deployed. Click the **Deploy** button before testing it again.